# Component Inheritance and DI for base class resolver

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-di

I have a different types of components but sharing some common algorithms. So I have decided to use Component Inheritance in Angular and tried with template method pattern.

Basically, I need to do a different implementation for some of the methods.

**Base Component**

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class ComponentBase<IComponentViewData> {    
    public isReadOnly: boolean;
    public data: any;
    public message: string;

    // template method
    saveData(){
        validateBeforeSave();
        save();
        afterSave();
    }
    save(){
    }
    protected abstract afterSave(){
    }
    protected abstract validateBeforeSave(): void;

    }
    exit(){

    }
}
```

**Child Component - Type A**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "app/component/childA.component.html",
    selector: "child-a"

})
export class ChildAComponent extends ComponentBase<IChildTypeAViewData> { //IChildTypeAViewData : IComponentViewData

    protected afterSave(){
      this.message ='Child A executed successfully'
    }

}
```

**ChildA.component.html**

It uses parent component fields and methods. Also embeds the common message templates that depends on parent component.

```
<div *ngIf="isReadOnly">
Show Data here
<button (click)="saveData()" />
<message></message>
</div>
```

**MessageComponent embedded in ChildA.component**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "app/common/message.html",
    selector: "message"

})
export class MessageComponent {

    constructor(@Host() hostComponent: ComponentBase<IComponentViewData>) {

    }
}
```

**message.html**

```
<div>{{ hostComponent.message }} </div>
<button (click)="exit()"></button>
```

**Problem:**

> As I embed message component in any of the Child types say ChildA,
>   ChildB I could not specify the proper derived class in Message
>   component  `@Host`. So dependency resolver provides an error `No
>   provider for ComponentBase`.

I used `@Host` in order to access the contained parent component's methods. Most of them are in abstract component.

Do we need to use [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver)? Or someother way we can try instead of Host?

Answer (score 3):

Edit `ChildA.component.ts` metadata with the following configuration:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: "app/component/childA.component.html",
  selector: "child-a",
  providers: [
   { provide: ComponentBase, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ChildAComponent) }
  ]
})
```

> The parent must cooperate by providing an alias to itself in the name of a class-interface token.

More info in the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#find-a-parent-by-its-class-interface).